# Force numpy, pytorch, tensorflow to use openblas

Tags: python

What is the best way to force numpy, pytorch and tensorflow to use openblas insteand of mkl on ubuntu?

Comment: You need to build it from source

Comment: have you any instructions for this?

Comment: Pytorch https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8561

Comment: Numpy https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/installing-numpy-with-openblas.html